# systemctl enable docker container service - failed

Tags: centos, docker, services, systemctl

I basically follow the document in AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_user_data_scripts.html

I created a Centos 7 and tried to install `docker`, `ese-agent` within my EC2 instance.

Here is my service file

**/etc/systemd/system/docker_container_ecs_agent.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Container %I
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm -f ecs-agent
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name ecs-agent --privileged --restart=on-failure:10 --volume=/var/run:/var/run --volume=/var/log/ecs/:/log:Z --volume=/var/lib/ecs/data:/data:Z --volume=/etc/ecs:/etc/ecs --net=host --env-file=/etc/ecs/ecs.config amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop ecs-agent

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I also did the `enable` and `start` command

```
sudo systemctl enable docker_container_ecs_agent.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/docker_container_ecs_agent.service to /etc/systemd/system/docker_container_ecs_agent.service.
sudo systemctl start docker_container_ecs_agent.service
```

However, when I inspect the status by typing `systemctl`, it threw the failed status.

```
UNIT                                                          LOAD   ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION

docker_container_ecs_agent.service                            loaded failed failed    docker_container_ecs_agent.service
```

### Update-Error logs

```
systemctl status docker_container_ecs_agent.service
● docker_container_ecs_agent.service - Docker Container ece-agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker_container_ecs_agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2019-07-15 16:43:59 UTC; 17s ago
  Process: 17464 ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop ecs-agent (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17386 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name ecs-agent --privileged --restart=on-failure:10 --volume=/var/run:/var/run --volume=/var/log/ecs/:/log:Z --volume=/var/lib/ecs/data:/data:Z --volume=/etc/ecs:/etc/ecs --net=host --env-file=/etc/ecs/ecs.config amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 17380 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker rm -f ecs-agent (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17386 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)


systemd[1]: Unit docker_container_ecs_agent.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: docker_container_ecs_agent.service failed.
systemd[1]: docker_container_ecs_agent.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Container ece-agent.
systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker_container_ecs_agent.service
systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Container ece-agent.
systemd[1]: Unit docker_container_ecs_agent.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: docker_container_ecs_agent.service failed.
```

### Update2-docker logs

```
docker run --privileged=true --restart=on-failure:10 --volume=/var/run:/var/run --volume=/var/log/ecs/:/log:Z --volume=/var/lib/ecs/data:/data:Z --volume=/etc/ecs:/etc/ecs --net=host --env-file=/etc/ecs/ecs.config amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Loading configuration
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Image excluded from cleanup: amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Image excluded from cleanup: amazon/amazon-ecs-pause:0.1.0
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Amazon ECS agent Version: 1.29.1, Commit: f95f731b
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Unable to get Docker client for version 1.27: version detection using MinAPIVersion: unsupported version: 1.27
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Unable to get Docker client for version 1.28: version detection using MinAPIVersion: unsupported version: 1.28
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Unable to get Docker client for version 1.29: version detection using MinAPIVersion: unsupported version: 1.29
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Unable to get Docker client for version 1.30: version detection using MinAPIVersion: unsupported version: 1.30
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Unable to get Docker client for version 1.31: version detection using MinAPIVersion: unsupported version: 1.31
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Unable to get Docker client for version 1.32: version detection using MinAPIVersion: unsupported version: 1.32
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Creating root ecs cgroup: /ecs
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Creating cgroup /ecs
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Loading state! module="statemanager"
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Event stream ContainerChange start listening...
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [WARN] Error getting valid credentials (AKID ): NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
        For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Registering Instance with ECS
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Remaining mem: 3787
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [ERROR] Unable to register as a container instance with ECS: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
        For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [INFO] Remaining mem: 3787
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [ERROR] Unable to register as a container instance with ECS: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
        For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
2019-07-15T19:57:44Z [ERROR] Error registering: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
        For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

Comment: does it work when you start it manually? does the container produce any logs when viewed with `docker logs`?

Comment: Seems I got a lot of error message lol. I will update later if I can't figure it out

Comment: @Bart I've updated my question and added logs

Comment: The case seems to broad, and the errors suggest issue with the container, as if something was missing. Check github issues for the image, e.g. https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/350 https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/605 https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1309 and similar, should give you a clue.

Comment: @Bart Turn out I need to attach `ecsInstancerole` role for my instance.

Comment: glad you managed to solve your issue!